# Setting up Browserify with Istanbul in Karma with ES6+

Tags: javascript, karma-runner, browserify, babeljs, istanbul

I am trying to use Karma to run tests **with accurate code coverage output** for my files that use ES6+ including ES7 async/await syntax.

## With only one source file: worked

As a start, I managed to make it work when I have only **one source file** (i.e. no `require` calls in my source files). I just told Karma to use `babel` on it and configured `babel-plugin-istanbul` on my `.babelrc`.

- `karma.conf.js`:

  ```
  preprocessors: {
      "test/*.js": [ "browserify" ],
      "lib/*.js": [ "babel" ]
  }
  ```

  Note that the `"coverage"` preprocessor is **not included on purpose**, because that's what [babel-plugin-istanbul](https://github.com/istanbuljs/babel-plugin-istanbul#karma) instructs to do (and it works indeed). Also, I do need to `browserify` the tests because there's a `require('chai')` in there.
- `.babelrc`:

  ```
  {
      "presets": [ "env" ],
      "env": {
          "test": {
              "plugins": [ "istanbul" ]
          }
      }
  }
  ```
- Great coverage results:

[image: correct coverage output in html reporter]

[image: correct coverage output in text-summary reporter]

## With multiple source files with `require()`: didn't work

Now I want to make this work in my real situation, which is a lot of source files with `require()` calls from one to the other. To make this work, instead of simply using the `babel` preprocessor, I had to use the `browserify` preprocessor, but now it seems to be ignoring my `.babelrc` and not instrumenting the code with istanbul coverage stuff:

- `karma.conf.js` was changed to:

  ```
      preprocessors: {
          "test/*.js": [ "browserify" ],
          "lib/*.js": [ "browserify" ]
      }
  ```

  Without this change, not even the tests would run. With it, the tests run, but the coverage does not work.
- Wrong coverage results:

[image: wrong coverage output in text-summary reporter]

**How can I fix this?**

---

## A repository for this question is available on GitHub

Since there's a lot going on, I decided to create a GitHub repo so that anyone can reproduce my situation instantly and easily:

- To see the first part that works:

  ```
  git clone https://github.com/papb/papb-stackoverflow-q-51812979.git
  cd papb-stackoverflow-q-51812979
  npm install
  npm test
  ```
- To see the part that doesn't work:

  ```
  git checkout doesnt-work
  npm test
  ```
- To see the full diff from the two (just three lines): [see the comparison on GitHub](https://github.com/papb/papb-stackoverflow-q-51812979/compare/doesnt-work)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OP here. I figured it out:

```
npm install browserify-istanbul
```

Add this to `karma.conf.js`:

```
browserify: {
    configure: function(bundle) {
        bundle.transform(require('browserify-istanbul')({
            ignore: ['test/*.js']
        }));
    }
}
```

Leave the `preprocessors` as they were (no `coverage` preprocessor!)

```
preprocessors: {
    "test/*.js": [ "browserify" ],
    "lib/*.js": [ "browserify" ]
}
```

That's it. You can get rid of the `.babelrc` and the `babel-plugin-istanbul`, they are not even necessary.